# Update ngModel if it's not null angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-ngmodel

I'd like to update `[(ngModel)]` using onclickevent **only if** the value is not null. Here's what i tried

click event method:

```
  setBiometricsStartTime() {
     let startTimeStore = new Date();
     if(this.startTime == undefined) 
     {
         this.startTime = new Date();
     }
     else 
     {
        this.startTime = startTimeStore;
     }
  }
```

html code:

```
[...]
   <mat-expansion-panel
    (opened)="personalDetailsOpenState = true" (closed)="personalDetailsOpenState = false" (click)="setBiometricsEndTime()
   </mat-expansion-panel>
[...]
```

Unfortunately, the model value is being generated on every click event.

Comment: please share your  html code also

Comment: where do you define `startTime`? do you already set its value somewhere

Comment: Either you can disable it or you can check it on your back code

Comment: @jmdavalos it's not been defined before. It just to set the startTime to the current datetime only if it the value is not null

Comment: hmm, where is `startTime` being used in the template?

Comment: thing is, with your code, `startTime` will always be set to have a value -- i don't understand why you're setting the "start" time when it already has a value (not null). so if you want to set `startTime` only when its value to not null, you mean if its value is currently null, it should always be null?

Comment: @jmdavalos Exaclty. That's the use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting it in else condition, try

```
if(!this.startTime || this.startTime==undefined) 
 {
     this.startTime = new Date();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check on  every click that the given model is null or not if its null then you can set value

you can use this code

```
setBiometricsStartTime() {
     let startTimeStore = new Date();
     if(this.startTime && this.startTime!=null) 
     {
         this.startTime = new Date();
     }

  }
```